# cannot get username when hosted on iis7 using system.environment.username

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-7

I have an asp.net web forms application which has authentication for users. I need to get the Username of the user that is currently logged onto windows. I have retrieved the Username using the following:

- WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
- Request.ServerVariables.Get("AUTH_USER");

My problem is when i host the application in IIS 7, the username is displayed as syssai-sql.

I am not sure what to do from here going foward.

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment? Are both the server and the client hosted members of the same Active Directory network?

Comment: Yes they both on the same domain and same active directory, my website is using windows authentication and is running on the app pool using a specific logon. Regardless of what i try i am only getting the app pool identity rather than the logged person credentials

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using [System.Environment.Username](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Environment.UserName(v=VS.110).aspx). That's to get the identity that the server process is running as. The reason it "works" when you test it locally is that they're the same, the web applications runs as your user account. The server behaves differently.

Instead, use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` property. In IIS, make sure the web application is set up for Windows Authentication and that Anonymous Authentication is disabled.

Additional Info: The [User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpContext.User(v=VS.110).aspx) property is an IPrincipal and has a [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property that contains the username of the user that's currently logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have just tried adding that to my app and it does not display any results. Its blank

Comment: @user3589806 Did you make sure that Windows authentication is checked in IIS for that site and that all the other authentication methods are disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Add the System.Security.Principal namespace and the try the following:

```
WindowsIdentity wi = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

Then you can access various properties like

```
wi.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that out now

Comment: If you use the implicitly typed `var` then you won't need to bother with the using statement.

Comment: Changed my text, with "use" I meant to import the namespace ;)

Comment: I just tried your solution Lukas and it works locally but not when hosted in IIS 7

Comment: Could you try:  WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();